# what is offline and online indexing in Elastic search? and when do we need to reindex?

Tags: elasticsearch

what is offline and online indexing in Elastic search?  I did my research but I couldn't find enough resources to see what these terms mean? any idea? and also when do we need to reindex? any examples would be great

The terms offline and online indexing are used here.

https://spark-summit.org/2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Streamlining-Search-Indexing-using-Elastic-Search-and-Spark-Holden-Karau.pdf

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'online' or 'offline' indexing, what are you trying to do? Regarding reindexing - Once you've set a mapping for an index Elasticsearch and indexed documents into it, Elasticsearch does not allow you to change these mappings (minus a few exceptions). Another thing that is not possible to do is to change the number of shards after an index was created, the desire to change these is usually the reason to reindex your data.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Reindexing

The most basic form if reindexing just copies one index to another.

I have used this form of reindexing to change a mapping. 
Elasticsearch doesn't allow you to change a mapping, so if you want to change a mapping you have to create a new index (index2) with a new mapping and then reindex. The reindex will fill that new mapping with the data of the old index.

The command below will move everything from index to index2.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_reindex?pretty' -d'
{
  "source": {
    "index": "index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index2"
  }
}'
```

You can also use reindexing to fill a new index with a part of the old one. You can do so by using a couple of parameters. The example below will copy the newest 1000 documents.

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "size": 1000,
  "source": {
    "index": "index",
    "sort": { "date": "desc" }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index2"
  }
}
```

For more examples about reindexing please have a look at the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-reindex.html).

## offline vs online indexing

In ONLINE mode the new index is built while the old index is accessible to reads and writes. any update on the old index will also get applied to the new index.

In OFFLINE mode the table is locked up front for any read or write, and then the new index gets built from the old index. No read or write operation is permitted on the table while the index is being rebuilt. Only when the operation is done is the lock on the table released and reads and writes are allowed again.

Comment: Thanks for your response. your answer on reindex is great! I just edited my question and pasted a link where I saw those terms and I am trying to understand what those terms mean

Comment: Thanks, The document you linked doesn't refer to either offline or online indexing though.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYicnlunDQ0 The link is provided by the person in this video and she definetly talks about offline or online indexing in this video. sorry for miscommunication

Comment: Could you please define any kind of timestamp? I can't exactly watch a 16min video right now haha

Comment: haha no worries. it starts from 3:01 but you my want to hear at least a minute or so.

Comment: These are the standard database online-offline modes, I have explained them in the original post. I hope this answers all of your questions :)